# Can't get to my nodejs server through web browser

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-web-services

Alright, so I setup a node.js server quite a while ago on a AWS EC2 micro server.  I was completely new to it and followed various tutorials to get it up and running.  It used nginx as a reverse proxy (I believe) and the server was listening on port 8124.

Now, the instance got restarted and I can't for the life of me get access to my server back.  I can ssh to it.  I can start the server.  I can send POST/PUT requests to it through my local command line, but my web browser gives me the 404 nginx page.

This is driving me up the wall - where in the browser/nginx/nodejs chain are things breaking down?

Please help - I'm horribly new at this at it must be a single line somewhere that's broken.  I just don't know enough to find it.

My /etc/nginx/sites-enables/default file simply contains

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8124/;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I figured it out.  I had to go directly into /etc/nginx/nginx.conf and in the server that was there

```
location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

I added the line

```
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8124/;
```

Oh thank god.  That was going to kill me.